# Calling Spring Security login method from Rest Webservice

Tags: spring, spring-security

i have a web application which uses Spring security for login.
we are creating mobile application for the same Web Application. we are trying to create webservice for login.

When we use below service URL, we are getting result in Postman(Tool to test webservice).

http://localhost:8080/App-web/static/login.do?username=User1&password=Pass1

Below is a sample code of spring security login of my application.

```
.formLogin()
  .loginPage( "/static/login.html" )
   .loginProcessingUrl( "/static/login.do" )
 .successHandler(customAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
 .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler())
 .usernameParameter( "username" )
 .passwordParameter( "password" )
  .and() .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/static/wait.html?msg=1")
```

Now the problem is we don't want to pass username and password in query string .So we tried to pass it in response body in json format in postman tool.But it is not working.
Any Idea to get this done?

Now second question is ,
We created another service and passing username and passwords in response body and we are retrieving the values in the service and tried to redirect/forward to actual login Url as shown in the code but we are not able to get it done.

We tried `ModeAndView("redirect:")` and `ModeAndView("Forward:")`. but still its not working.

Comment: Don't use a form based login for a web based client. Use either basic/digest authentication or use a form of OAuth2.

Comment: The default of form login is `POST`, so it shouldn't work with `GET`. If it works with get you changed the default. Show your full Spring Security configuration. However, Deinum is right, don*t use form login for REST clients.

Comment: i m passing parameters in body as x-www-form-urlencoded. Now the issue is , when we send request from Ipad (IOS device) the login as working and application is working fine. but when we execute same code from android device the authentication is done successfully but the next webservice request fails and in logs it says org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied....what is the difference between ipad call and android call.